# How to make data in fields in one table appear in another table PHPmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

I seriously need help. I having been chewing this gravel for days now and no headway.

I am having a database in Phpmyadmin created and contains two tables - students table and the Accounts table.

Students table already contain the following fields and data: SerialNo, AdmissionNumber, Surname, FirstName and OtherNames. How do I automatically include these fields in the Account Table? I have already created a relationship like this:[relations between students table and Account table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GasxV.jpg) but I can't see these fields in the Account table appearing when I SELECT * FROM Accounts

What am I missing or getting wrong? I need answer please, help.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (and phpMyAdmin) relations allow MySQL to interact with the data in a particular way, knowing that the two tables are related. This can, for instance, prevent you from removing a student from the `Students` table while they still have a balance due in `Accounts`. One way phpMyAdmin can use this relationship is to show the value that's represented by a foreign key, rather than the key itself (so showing a student's name instead of the primary key that represents them, for instance). However, that doesn't mean you've merged the two tables; when you run `SELECT *` it's still treating that table as an independent table.

There are two ways to accomplish what you want; you can either create a view or join the tables. One way, which probably isn't really what you want, could be `SELECT * FROM Students, Account WHERE Students.SerialNo=Account.SerialNo`. There are several join types available (inner, left, right, outer) and which one you will use depends what exactly you want the results to look like.

Comment: Hhmmm... Thanks so much Isaac Bennetch, I so much appreciate your contributions.